# probleme with absolute layout while converting jar into exe on launch4j

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j, absolutelayout

i've finished my **java application** now i need to convert it into an **.exe** file i've done some research and i found that **Launch4j** is the less problems wrapper , i've done everything with success only when it comes to **run the .exe file** it shows me this error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
at gestion.des.stages.alarme.MainStageListe.initComponents(MainStageListe.java:56)
at gestion.des.stages.alarme.MainStageListe.<init>(MainStageListe.java:28)
at gestion.des.stages.alarme.MainStageListe$4.run(MainStageListe.java:266)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
```

I really don't know how to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JAR file containing that class to the launch4j options.